# How can I return a true/false value depending if a bit value is 1 or 0?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I return a `true`/`false` value depending if a bit value is 1 or 0? The table has a list of usernames and a bit value of 1 or 0. I want to check if the bit value is 1 or 0.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
boolean value = resultSet.getInt("columnName") != 0;
```

It will be `false` when it's `0`, otherwise `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ValueDao {
    public static final String SELECT_VALUE = "SELECT VALUE FROM MY_TABLE"; // WHERE clause?

    private Connection connection;

    public ValueDao(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public boolean hasValue(String value) throws SQLException {
        boolean hasValue = false;

        if (value != null) {
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                st = connection.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String x = rs.getString(1);
                    if (value.equals(x)) {
                        hasValue = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);  // you write these cleanup methods.
            DatabaseUtils.close(st);
        }

        return hasValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Taking some time out of your day to do this is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can run query in java on connection like:

```
//Say you have a Connection conn
//Say column for bit value is USER_BIT 
//and say 1st bit we are looking for
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select USER_BIT & 1 from USERS where USER_ID ='123'");
```

NOTE: Above code is for illustration. You might need to change it as per your need.